# Switching between git branches persists unwanted folders

Tags: python, git

I'm having an issue where folders exist (and are being tracked) on branch `A` and, when switching to branch `B`, those folders carry over, even though they are not tracked on branch `B` (a simple `ls -la` and `git ls-files` proves this). While on branch B, running `git ls-files` on the folders returns nothing (it will return everything on branch `A`) and doing `git status` doesn't show any changes for either branch. One interesting thing is that the unwelcomed folders on branch `B` contain a single `__pycache__` folder with the names of the files that are on branch `A` (which have been converted to `*.cpython-39.pyc` files). Both `**/__pycache__/` and `**/*.pyc` are in `.gitignore` for both branches. I've noticed this doesn't happen unless a change is made on branch `A` first, but it doesn't have to be a change that is to, or inside of, that folder.

**I've seen similar questions to this and tried `git reset --hard` and `git clean -d --dry-run` (and `git clean -xf`) but no luck**.

### Edit:

Let me clarify some things: 1) With the branch I don't want the folders on (branch B), the folders are not present on the remote and are only shown, and seemingly ignored, locally. Running `ls` shows that this folder exists on both branches, `git status` shows both branches to be clean and up-to-date, and `git ls-tree` on both branches shows what I expect to happen (the folder to not exist on branch B, but to exist on branch A).

This is what it looks like if I were to run `tree -L 3` on both branches (and I'm not explicitly throwing `folder1` into my gitignore, only the strings I mentioned above):

```
**Branch A**:

project    
│
└───folder1
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │

**Branch B**:

project   
│
│   file011.txt
│   file012.txt
└───folder1 <-- "ignored" from here down, but still exists
│   │   └───__pycache__
|   |   |   |   file011.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   |   |   file012.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   |   |
```

Comment: Can you show us output of `git status`, `ls` and `git ls-tree` when you are switching between branches so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: My best guess for why the folder remains would be that there are files which are untracked/ignored in the folder. Git wont just delete files when you swap branches (unless they are tracked/versioned).

Comment: btw. `git clean -d --dry-run` should only show which files will be cleaned away, not actually remove them (you have to use -f instead of --dry-run to actually remove anything). Also if the files you want to remove are ignored you will have to add either -x (to also remove ignored files) or -X (to only remove ignored files). try running `git clean -h` to see what the different parameters does.

Comment: @eftshift0 Updated post to reflect these requests, thanks

Comment: @Kim I did try `git clean` without --dry-run, I should've mentioned that. Tried it with your additional suggestions but still not getting desired outcome. I updated my post to give more insight if it helps, thank you for your time

Comment: Is it possible a (Windows?) process is keeping a handle on those `__pycache__` files, preventing Git to do the proper cleanup when switching branches?

Comment: @VonC that's definitely a possibility. The only thing I can think of is the actual windows file explorer because I have my vscode running within WSL. Thanks for that realization!